# How is the orthogonal projection on to the span of the columns of a matrix determined by a chosen inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, matrix-equations, linear-transformations

I know that of course a orthogonal projection must be orthogonal for a chosen inner product.

But how can I find a new orthogonal projection based on $P=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$, if I have dot product defined as $(x,y)=x^TMy$?

Comment: in the title, colons should be columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adjoint $A^*$ of $A$ relative to an inner product is defined by 
$$
(Ax,y) = (x,A^*y) \quad \forall x,y
$$
For the usual inner product, we have $A^* = A^T$.  For this new inner product, we need to have
$$
(Ax)^T M y = x^T M (A^*y) \implies\\
x^T A^TM y = x^T M A^* y \implies\\
A^TM = MA^* \implies\\
A^* = M^{-1}A^T M
$$
We then have
$$
P = A(A^*A)^{-1}A^* = 
A(M^{-1}A^T M A)^{-1} (M^{-1}A^T M) =\\
A(A^T M A)^{-1} A^T M
$$

Comment: Do I understand that right transpose A^(T) and the complex one A^(H) are just forms of the adjoint and are depended on the chosen inner product?

Comment: @Samuel yes! Those are the adjoints for the standard inner product over $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb C^n$ respectively